# Surviving generations keep increasing while running Solr query

Tags: java, solr

I am testing a query with jSolr (7.4) because I believe it is causing a memory leak in my program. But I am not sure it is indeed a memory leak, so I call for advices!

This method is called several times during the running time of my indexing program (should be able to run weeks / months without any problems). That's why I am testing it in a loop that I profile with Netbeans Profiler.

If I simply retrieve the id from all documents (there are 33k) in a given index :

```
public class MyIndex {
    // This is used as a cache variable to avoid querying the index everytime the list of documents is needed
 private List<MyDocument> listOfMyDocumentsAlreadyIndexed = null;

 public final List<MyDocument> getListOfMyDocumentsAlreadyIndexed() throws SolrServerException, HttpSolrClient.RemoteSolrException, IOException {

  SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery("*:*");

  query.addField("id");
  query.setRows(Integer.MAX_VALUE); // we want ALL documents in the index not only the first ones

  SolrDocumentList results = this.getSolrClient().
    query(query).getResults();

    /**
    * The following was commented for the test, 
    * so that it can be told where the leak comes from.
    *
    */

    //            listOfMyDocumentsAlreadyIndexed = results.parallelStream()
    //                    .map((doc) -> { // different stuff ...
    //                                  return myDocument;
    //                                  })
    //                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return listOfMyDocumentsAlreadyIndexed; 
    /** The number of surviving generations 
     *  keeps increasing whereas if null is 
     * returned then the number of surviving 
     * generations is not increasing anymore
    */
}
```

I get this from the profiler (after nearly 200 runs that could simulate a year of runtime for my program) :

[image]

The object that is most surviving is `String` :

[image]

Is the growing number of surviving generations the expected behaviour while querying for all documents in the index ?

If so is it the root cause of the "OOM Java heap space" error that I get after some time on the production server as it seems to be from the stacktrace :

```
Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at org.noggit.CharArr.resize(CharArr.java:110)
at org.noggit.CharArr.reserve(CharArr.java:116)
at org.apache.solr.common.util.ByteUtils.UTF8toUTF16(ByteUtils.java:68)
at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.readStr(JavaBinCodec.java:868)
at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.readStr(JavaBinCodec.java:857)
at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.readObject(JavaBinCodec.java:266)
at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.readVal(JavaBinCodec.java:256)
at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.readSolrDocument(JavaBinCodec.java:541)
at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.readObject(JavaBinCodec.java:305)
at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.readVal(JavaBinCodec.java:256)
at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.readArray(JavaBinCodec.java:747)
at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.readObject(JavaBinCodec.java:272)
at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.readVal(JavaBinCodec.java:256)
at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.readSolrDocumentList(JavaBinCodec.java:555)
at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.readObject(JavaBinCodec.java:307)
at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.readVal(JavaBinCodec.java:256)
at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.readOrderedMap(JavaBinCodec.java:200)
at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.readObject(JavaBinCodec.java:274)
at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.readVal(JavaBinCodec.java:256)
at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.unmarshal(JavaBinCodec.java:178)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.BinaryResponseParser.processResponse(BinaryResponseParser.java:50)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:614)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:255)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:244)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.process(SolrRequest.java:194)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.query(SolrClient.java:942)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.query(SolrClient.java:957)
```

Would increasing the heap space ("-Xmx") from 8GB to anything greater solve the problem definitely or would it just postpone it ? What can be done to workaround this ?

**Edit some hours later**

If `null` is returned from the method under test (`getListOfMyDocumentsAlreadyIndexed`) then the number of surviving generations remains stable throughout the test :

[image]

So even though I was NOT using the result of the query for this test (because I wanted to focuse only on where the leak happened) it looks like returning an instance variable (even though it was null) is not a good idea. I will try to remove it.

**Edit even later**

I noticed that the surviving generations were still increasing in the telemetry tab when I was profiling "defined classes" ("focused (instrumented)") whereas it was stable when profiling "All classes" ("General (sampled)"). So I am not sure it solved the problem :

[image: Profiling defined classes (focused)]

[image: Profiling all classes (sampled)]

Any hint greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: The profiler (or `jheap` etc.) should be able to tell you _which_ objects are being kept alive. That'll give you a better hint about what's being left around and possibly why they're still there

Comment: Thanks @MatsLindh I added the table from the profiler. String are kept alive. What should I take away from that ? The "id" that I retrieve is stored as String so it may be the culprit, but what should I do ?

Comment: Then we might get into what you're doing with the results after you've retrieved them from Solr; are you keeping them around in some way? Have you tried expanding the references in the profiler to see what code is keeping those references around inside your own code? I'm not used to reading profiling information from that specific profiler, but I'm guessing the noggit reference is only where the object is created, not necessarily what the live references to it are.

Comment: Trying to answer your comment, I tried to return null from the method I was testing instead of returning an instance variable that I was previously populated (but which population was removed for the sake of the test). And the surviving generation number did stay stable. I will try to explain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem stems from the following line :

```
query.setRows(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

This should not be done according to this article :

> The rows parameter for Solr can be used to return more than the default of 10 rows. I have seen users successfully set the rows parameter to 100-200 and not see any issues. However, setting the rows parameter higher has a big memory consequence and should be avoided at all costs.

So problem have been solved by retrieving the documents by chunks of 200 docs following [this solr article on pagination](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_7/pagination-of-results.html) :

```
SolrQuery q = (new SolrQuery(some_query)).setRows(r).setSort(SortClause.asc("id"));
String cursorMark = CursorMarkParams.CURSOR_MARK_START;
boolean done = false;
while (! done) {
  q.set(CursorMarkParams.CURSOR_MARK_PARAM, cursorMark);
  QueryResponse rsp = solrServer.query(q);
  String nextCursorMark = rsp.getNextCursorMark();
  doCustomProcessingOfResults(rsp);
  if (cursorMark.equals(nextCursorMark)) {
    done = true;
  }
  cursorMark = nextCursorMark;
}
```

Please note : you should not exceed 200 documents in `setRows` otherwise the memory leak still happens (e.g. for 500 it does happen).

Now the profiler gives much better results regarding surviving generations as they do not increase over time anymore.

[image]

However the method is much slower.